# Install java JRE on wine

Tags: wine, java

So I've got a working Java installation in my wineprefix, which I did somewhere in 2017 on Ubuntu 16.04. Back then I installed wine-staging and had to do a silent install of Java:

```bsh
wine jre-8u161-windows-x64.exe /s
```

After that I upgraded to 18.04, removed wine staging and installed wine-devel from the Ubuntu repos (but I kept my wineprefix). So I still have a working installation on Ubuntu 18.04.

Now I'm trying to replicate my setup on another Ubuntu 18.04 system, but I can no longer get Java installed. I tried with Ubuntu's `wine-stable` (3.0), `wine-development` (3.6) and with Wine Staging's `winehq-stable` (4.0). All of them fail. Then I tried going back to a really old jre installer (8u25). Even that fails.

```
0036:err:ole:CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx apartment not initialised
0034:err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"installexe" returned 1627
```

Is there some magic step I'm forgetting or is this just a regression/bug?

Comment: Does [this WineHQ question](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23073) help?

Comment: That's way too old.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just **copying the entire wine prefix** to the other PC. Obviously not an ideal solution, but it worked in my case. I just had to let wine recreate the links in `dosdevices` and then I was set.

I don't know what special stuff the installer does, maybe it's possible to just make a tarball with all the files, let them extract to `Program Files` and run a `.reg` file. Maybe I'll investigate this solution sometime.

Another possible solution (if you need `javaws.exe`) is [OpenWebStart](https://openwebstart.com/). It installs without a problem in Wine. However unfortunately I couldn't get the `.jnlp` file I needed to run working. I got a splash screen of the application, but it then sadly crashed with this error `net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Unknown Main-Class. Could not determine the main class for this application.` I didn't try to solve this issue.